# Should I use Array or NSArray in Swift

Tags: swift

I know the difference between Array and NSArray, one is a **Struct**, another is a **Class**, what makes me confusion, under what kind of situation, should I use Array/NSArray?

Answer (score 5):

Use Array when writing Swift code. That's it.

In rare cases when you have to interact with an API that requires `NSArray`, then you can cast (if needed) your Swift Array into (or from) an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with array in swift. because

`Array` is a struct so it is value type in Swift. `NSArray` is an immutable Objective C class, therefore it is a reference type in Swift.'
but whenever you need, you can cast it to `NSArray`